# accessed via reference and Method call expected error in Android

Tags: java, android

I am starting a new activity from a fragment like so:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     startActivity(BarCodeActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), destinationID));
 }
```

This gives me no problem.

But when I do the same later on with a different activity in the same fragment, I get the error: Method call expected:

```
public void onClick(View view){
     startActivity(TestPagerActivity().newIntent(getActivity(), customerObject.getId(), destinationID));
}
```

I'll change it to:

```
startActivity(new TestPagerActivity().newIntent(getActivity(), customerObject.getId(), destinationID));
```

and the error will go away, but now I get the warning accessing static member via instance reference.  Any ideas how I can fix this or what is going on?

Comment: You have an extra pair of parentheses which are unnecessary (). Remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Error 1:** Method call expected

You cannot create an instance without using `new` keyword like you are trying to do at

```
TestPagerActivity().newIntent(getActivity().....
```

**Error 2:** accessing static member via instance reference

A static method should be called without any instance reference, just by the name of the Class.

**Solution:**

Change to

```
startActivity(TestPagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), customerObject.getId(), destinationID));
```